# Mongoose+NestJS - query values showing as null in mongoose logs, unable to filter anything because of this

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I've run into a strange scenario after updating mongoose version, no find or where queries are working.
I ran mongoose in debug mode to check the logs and found that all the filter values passed are going as null in mongoose logs.

[image: Highlighted the query written in code and the one picked by Mongoose]

Did anyone face a similar situation before? Please help.

Comment: After your `studentModel.find` can you `console.log(student.getFilter());` please, what does it output? Can you remove the `await` keyword first please.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `models` project had a different version of `mongoose` listed as the dependency.
Putting that under `devDependencies` instead of `dependencies` allowed the project to use its version of `mongoose`.

I am not sure why `mongoose` dependency didn't get deduped for the `models` project in the first place